# I want to return data form a table depending on whats in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `passenger_table` and a table `users`!

**passenger_table**

```
user_id  j_id
1          1
34         1
54         1
```

**users**

```
user_id  Firstname  Lastname
1         Patrick    Connell    
34         John       Murphy
54         Connell    Jones
```

I know this might be straight forward enough but I just want to loop out all the users firstnames and lastnames where journey id is = 1.

So the output would be the 3 users mentioned above first and lastnames.

This is what I got so far.....

```
//Get passenger id
$id = $_GET['id'];
$resultp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM passenger_journey WHERE j_id=$id")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$rowp = mysql_fetch_array($resultp);
$passenger_id = $rowp['user_id'];


//Get Passenger Details
$resultpd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$passenger_id")
or die(mysql_error()); 


while($rowpd = mysql_fetch_array($resultpd)) {
    echo '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $rowpd['user_id'] . '">' . $rowpd['firstname'] . ' ' . $rowpd['lastname'] . '</a><br/>';
}
```

At the moment I can only retrieve one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join the table, on the associative ID. Read more about table joins here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, p.j_id 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN passenger_table p ON p.user_id=u.user_id 
WHERE p.j_id=1;
```

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate as the OP probably doesn't know why your code works (but +1 for SQL solution ;)

Comment: true, just added in some info and link to documentation.

Comment: I'll second kingkero's comment and +1 :)

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN and not INNER JOIN?